# Windows Batch File - a series of IF statements displays asynchronous behavior?

Tags: batch-file, command

I have a series of IF statements in a windows batch file like so:

```
IF %One% == YES ( 
   myprogram1
)

IF %Two% == YES ( 
   myprogram2
)

IF %Three% == YES ( 
   myprogram3
)
```

even if they are all true, only the first will execute.  How do I get them to wait?  If I execute multiple programs within a single IF statement it behaves synchronously, running one after the other.  I don't want N! if statements for obvious reasons.

I'm executing this batch file from a `.NET` process and redirecting the output so I don't think `start /wait` will work.  I can't have it start a new window.  What am I missing?

Comment: You need to post your actual code. Attempting to generalise leads to speculation, assumption and theorising.

Comment: If one of the programs is another batch and you don't use `call` the actual batch is terminated on invoking the other. Also some programs invoke a different other and immediately terminate itself so the batch get's control back at once. Try calc.exe which invokes Calculator_10...  an UWP program in Windows10 for this.